# In which cases should one override onDestroy()?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I'm reading up on the activity lifecycle, and reading the documentation on starting and destroying activities, at the follow link:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

The following text is from the link:

> **Destroy the Activity**
>
> While the activity's first lifecycle callback is onCreate(), its very
>   last callback is onDestroy(). The system calls this method on your
>   activity as the final signal that your activity instance is being
>   completely removed from the system memory.
>
> Most apps don't need to implement this method because local class
>   references are destroyed with the activity and your activity should
>   perform most cleanup during onPause() and onStop(). However, if your
>   activity includes background threads that you created during
>   onCreate() or other long-running resources that could potentially leak
>   memory if not properly closed, you should kill them during
>   onDestroy().

Can someone give an example(or examples) of background threads or "other long-running resources" that would warrant an onDestroy() override, and explain how they avoid the regular onDestroy() cleanup?

Clarification: I understand how onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy() work, that's not what I'm asking about. I'm asking for a more in-depth clarification of what would warrant overriding onDestroy()

Answer (score 2):

Well, onDestroy() is a method called by the framework when your activity is closing down. It is called to allow your activity to do any shut-down operations it may wish to do. The method doesn't really have anything to do with garbage collection. In particular, it has nothing to do with C++ destuctors (despite its name).

This method gives your program a chance to do things like cleanup resources, so that they don't pollute the associated application. If you have no shut-down operations to do, you don't need to override it. The base class does essentially nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `cleanUp logic` in `onDestroy()` when you can't put it in `onPause()` or `onStop()` .

Example : You want your activity to do something only when it is finishing i.e, only once. You can't put that logic in `onStop()` because it is called whenever your activity `loses focus` or in `onPause()` - called whenever your activity `goes to background` .

Comment: If you code you activities assuming that they might be destroyed after onStop(), you can't go wrong.  There is no guarantee that onDestroy() will be called unless you are using finish().

Comment: yes, you are right.. I was merely pointing out when the OP might find overriding onDestroy() useful.. Never said he had to override it always.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've already read what you've said in the quoted part of the question.